# F#/FAKE NuGet Private Feed Authentication

Tags: authentication, f#, nuget, artifactory, f#-fake

I am trying to use FAKE to restore my NuGet packages as part of my build script but I need to use a private feed (Artifactory) that requires authentication.

I came across this while searching for a solution. 
https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/issues/119

It indicates the issue was resolved via a commit, but I wasn't able to determine where the commit or what version the commit went into and there doesn't seem to be any documented way of usage.

```
Target "RestorePackages" (fun _ -> 
     "./**/*.sln"
     |> RestoreMSSolutionPackages (fun p ->
         { p with
             Sources = "{url}" :: p.Sources
             OutputPath = outputDir
             Retries = 4 })
 )
```

I looked through the source and found the above snippet though it appears there is no parameters related to authentication unless they're passed into the Sources parameter?

Has anyone had any experience or knowledge on getting FAKE package restore to work with authentication?

Comment: can't you set {url} to the pre-authenticated nuget feed?

Comment: Have you considered using paket? You can use it from F# directly, and it supports authenticated sources http://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/nuget-dependencies.html

Comment: @FyodorSoikin interesting, never heard of Paket. Is there a working example of Paket in a FAKE build script?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not aware of such example myself, but I'm sure it must exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add credentials to your nuget.config and specify it in your Restore.

```
{ p with
     Sources = p.Sources
     OutputPath = outputDir
     Retries = 4 
     ConfigFile = Some "./tools/nuget/nuget.config" }
```

And then add something like this to your config.

```
 <packageSource>
     <add key="feedName" value="http://example.com/Feed.svc" />
 </packageSource>
 <packageSourceCredentials>
     <feedName>
         <add key="Username" value="xxx" />
         <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="secret" />
     </feedName>
 </packageSourceCredentials>
```

https://docs.nuget.org/consume/nuget-config-settings

Comment: To all reading this now. Please look at paket. It works a lot better and faster then nuget.

Answer (score 1):

In the mean time the "ConfigFile" field is not (no longer) available. However you should be able to leverage the hierarchical nature of the nuget.config files (explained here : https://docs.nuget.org/consume/nuget-config-file).

Please also refer the chapter "Credentials for package source" for storing the password in an encrypted fashion.

Comment: By the way, I saw that the bootstrapping support (http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/apidocs/fake-boot.html) does support using credentials for private feeds as parameters... However I could not find such support in the RestorePAckageHelper http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/apidocs/fake-restorepackagehelper.html